# I need to design 182 RGB LED array circuit

Tags: led, bjt, current-source, constant-current, led-matrix

I looked for designs for PWM dimming RGB LED arrays on the internet, and I found this circuit with a current mirror:

[image]

As the title says, I am designing an LED panel with 182 RGB LEDs.

I think the design in the figure would work,  but it only has a few LEDs.
I don't know what would happen if there were more LEDs and transistors attached.

I want to properly design and calculate this current mirror circuit from theory.

Is there a better topology?

Specifications:

- Operation voltage: 24V
- LED part: [150282M153310 Korean](https://www.digikey.kr/product-detail/ko/w%C3%BCrth-elektronik/150282M153310/732-150282M153310DKR-ND/12385064),
  [150282M153310 USA](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/w%C3%BCrth-elektronik/150282M153310/12375060)
- continuous current: 20 mA
- maximum forward voltage of

  - R: 2.4 V
  - G: 3.2 V
  - B: 3.2 V
- dimming method: PWM (17 kHz)

The design would look like this:

[image]

Comment: that relies on the Hfe of the BJT for current setting, and that varies with temp and between individual transistors, even from the same batch.

Comment: I knew higher Hfe value is good. but If each bjt has different value cause temperature or some reason, what it cause some problem in my circuit?

Comment: Higher Hfe is bad if you've designed for a lower value.

Comment: Brightness will be your biggest problem.  Mixing RGB to get a particular color means controlling the for the  R, G, and B LEDs separately.

Comment: @JRE what value is bad to higher Hfe? I don't get it.
And I don't care RGB mixing. My purpose is make powerful dimable RGB light.

Comment: Higher Hfe can be good or bad.  If you designed a circuit for a transistor with a low Hfe, then replaced it with a transistor with a much higher Hfe, then the circuit won't work properly.  In that case, higher Hfe is bad.  If you are designing a new circuit, you may want a lot of amplification - in that case, a higher Hfe is good.

Comment: Why do you have different numbers of LED's in your design, sometimes 2, sometimes 3, sometimes 4 LED's? How are the 182 divided-up?

Comment: //MicroservicesOnDDD im sorry too late, LED part has each RGB leds and its has different forward voltage. R led's forward voltage is 2V and G,B has 3.2V.

Comment: If you want to go mainly discrete: series group LEDs by common dimming such that there remains enough voltage drop for an emitter resistor and \$V_{CE}\$ at a decent \$h_{FE}\$. Chose resistor and base voltage for the wanted current. Dim by shunting that base voltage instead of switching a diode current of 1.3 A minimum.